# ¿Cómo realizar una función de más de tres condicionales aplicada a 10 columnas al tiempo?

Tags: r, rstudio

Buen día,

Tengo un data frame compuesto por 82 filas y 10 columnas, cada fila corresponde a un sitio, y cada columna a un año. Los datos corresponden a un porcentaje de contaminación, y quisiera saber cómo podría aplicar una función de clasificación a cada uno de los años correspondientes a las columnas de la siguiente forma:

```
Si es mayor a 0.75 -> Área de contaminación alta
Si está entre 0.50 y 0.75 -> Área de contaminación media
Si está entre 0.25 a 0.50 -> Área de contaminación moderada
Si está entre 0.10 a 0.25 -> Área de contaminación marginal
```

Estuve intentando algo cómo el siguiente código:

```
f= function(x) {if (x > 0.75) {texto <- paste(x, 'Área de contaminación Alta')print(texto)clasif[x] <- 'Área de contaminación Alta'} else {if (x > 0.50) {texto <- paste(i, 'Área de contaminación media')print(texto) clasif[x] <- 'Área de contaminación media'} else {texto <- paste(i, 'Área de contaminación moderada')print(texto)clasif[x] <- 'Área de contaminación moderada'}}}
```

Para luego aplicar la función sapply con cada una de las columnas, pero no he tenido resultado.

¡Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más práctica es usar la función `cut()` para convertir en un `factor` que contempla cada uno de los rangos, y adicionalmente definirle la etiqueta que queremos. Te hago notar que hay un rango que deberías incluir, el del los valores menores a 0.10 (mas allá que no los tengas):

```
set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(x =runif(100))

df$fct_c <- cut(df$x, 
                breaks = c(-Inf, .10, .25, .50, .75, Inf), 
                labels = c('Sin contaminación',
                           'Área de contaminación marginal',
                           'Área de contaminación moderada',
                           'Área de contaminación media',
                           'Área de contaminación alta'))

head(df)

           x                          fct_c
1 0.64690284    Área de contaminación media
2 0.39422576 Área de contaminación moderada
3 0.61850181    Área de contaminación media
4 0.47689114 Área de contaminación moderada
5 0.13609719 Área de contaminación marginal
6 0.06738439              Sin contaminación
```

Comment: Buenas Noches Patricio, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que la lista apareciera con los nombres de los sitios y el año, ya que busco precisamente saber qué sitios son los de contaminación alta, moderada, media y marginal, lo que me has recomendado ha funcionado perfectamente, pero quisiera que adicionara esas características, que son importantes para mi. Nuevamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: Una vez que tienes las etiquetas, para agregarle el sitio por ejemplo, podrías hacer `paste(df$fct_c, df$sitio)`